SignalR Clients.Group not receiving messages in Angular frontend
I am using SignalR in .NET 4.8 with Angular, and I'm trying to receive chat messages in a group. Below is my code:
Server-side (C#):
public void SendMessageToTestGroup(string message, string senderName)
{
    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    var users = _connection.Where(k => k.Key == connectionId).Select(k => new { k.Value.User, k.Value.Room });
    Clients.Group("TestGroup").ReceiveTestGroupMessage(senderName, message);
}

public void JoinToTestGroup()
{
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "TestGroup");
    Clients.Group("TestGroup").NewRoomCreated("");
    SendAllGroups();
}

Client-side (Angular):
this.proxy_48.on('ReceiveTestGroupMessage', (user: string, message: string) => {
    debugger
    console.log(message);
    this.messages = [...this.messages, { user, message }];
    this.messages$.next(this.messages);
});

I'm adding the user to the group using the JoinToTestGroup method. However, I'm not receiving messages on the frontend when using Clients.Group("TestGroup").ReceiveTestGroupMessage(senderName, message);.
To test, I changed the code to Clients.All.ReceiveTestGroupMessage(senderName, message); and I was able to receive the message. Can you please suggest why Clients.Group("TestGroup").ReceiveTestGroupMessage(senderName, message); is not working?
